# Property not found - complaints about `constraints`

Tags: grails

I wanted to add some fields in my `.gsp` file. Therefore i copied some code from the `_form.gsp` view.

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: p, field: 'gender', 'error')} 
     required">
    <label for="gender"> 
        <g:message code="t.gender.label" default="Gender" /> 
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>
    <g:select name="gender"
              from="${p?.constraints.gender.inList}" required=""
              value="${p?.gender}"
              valueMessagePrefix="t.gender" />
</div>
```

The error complaints at `constraints`. It's not able to find `constraints`. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing it via the instance (p in your example) access it using the fully qualified domain class name. For example:

```
MyDomain.constraints.gender.inList
```